# window resize function randomly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'm working on a responsive menu, using JS/jQuery. The menu works, but if you resize the window within the 'mobile' area (1024px), the function for the dropdown tabs to toggle will randomly stop working..

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function mobile(){
        $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('#menuM').toggle();
    });
}

$(window).resize(mobile);
mobile();

function resMenu() {
    var sTest = $('#sizeTest').css('float');
    $('#sizeTestText').text("current sizeTest = " + sTest);

    if (sTest === 'left') {
        $('nav').attr('id', 'menuM');
        $('#menuM').hide();
        $('#menuM .has-sub').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#menuM ul li').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('tap');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('tap');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('nav').attr('id', 'menu');
        $('#menu').show();
        $('#menuM ul li').removeClass('tap');
    }

    var navTest = $('nav').attr('id');
    $('#linkTest').text("current nav id = " + navTest);
}

$(window).resize(resMenu);
resMenu();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an event handler inside an event handler, refactored your code looks like

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('#menuM').toggle();
    });
});
```

As the resize event fires hundreds, maybe thousands of times when the window is resized, you've just added a few thousand click handlers.

The many, many click handlers **are cancelling each other out**, hence it's  only working when you have an odd number of click handlers, when you end up with an even number of click handlers, for instance when the resize event fires 1032 times, the `toggle` effect will be cancelled out.

Comment: the menu-toggle function always works, it's the #menuM .has-sub click function that is causing the error. However, if I put it in a $(document).ready(); function, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You have the same issue in both functions, I just chose the first one to illustrate. You have event handlers for click inside event handlers for resize, it's never going to work properly that way, **never ever** !

Comment: Any idea why the click handler doesn't work when it's put outside of the resize function, then?

Comment: Nope, I can't really duplicate that code, you have conditions and stuff for adding the click event handlers, and you're not really getting how it works, which is why I didn't attempt a complete solution, but instead tried to explain what the issue is, and that once you've added an event handler, it's there, and you just keep adding the same event handler over and over, and the callback is executed hundreds of times when you click something.

Comment: @adneo I appreciate your clarification and answer.. if you have a second, can you take a look at this and tell me if it makes more sense to you, as I have achieved the objective now: